# Porting a C# SerialPort application to Python and PySerial with equivelant calls

Tags: python, c#, pyserial

I currently have some older test application that was written in C# that I want to extend with other functionality, but utilize Python/PySerial to do it.

Overall, I have found a few other helpful SO threads (example: [C# .NET serial port connects, doesn't read or write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637414/c-sharp-net-serial-port-connects-doesnt-read-or-write)), as well as the PySerial docs helpful, yet I am facing some issues with the communication. Below is an abbreviated example of how things are being passed (with some changes in the messages for IP):

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                        
_serialPort.WriteLine("login_string");
_serialPort.WriteLine("debug_string");

_serialPort.WriteLine("a message");
```

In Python, I have:

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial(
            port="COM1",
            baudrate=115200,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            dsrdtr=True,
        )

port.write(b'login_string\n')
port.write(b'debug_string\n')

port.write(b'a message\n')
```

I believe this is correct because I have to add the `\n` newline character at the end and convert to bytes using the prepended `b` on the string.

I did try to research, and I thought I saw that strings are represented as UTF-16 in C#? Does it get converted to UTF-8? It would make sense since the bytesize is set to 8 bits.

I also believe that the `dsrdtr` flag is required since `_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;` is used.

I feel like this should work, but I'm not sure, and I feel like I'm just spinning my wheels at this point in an echo chamber. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: _"I feel like this should work, but I'm not sure,"_ - why not test it, then?

Comment: @Fildor I have tested it, with no success, hence why I am posting here.

Comment: Where and why and how did the test fail?

Comment: I see the port opens, but I'm not getting any feedback or seeing the same results.

Now, the example code looks like it sends a login/debug string, then just sends a command string and should be good to go to communicate. Since the process seems "so simple", I wonder if it's something that I'm doing incorrectly with the library. If that makes sense. I am trying to figure out the best way to debug it moving forward.

Comment: It feels a lot like dealing with a blackbox device, which is where my issue arises. It feels my code is ~1:1 with the example code.